# Tensorflow error: ValueError: Variable already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True or reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, yolo, bounding-box

I've taken code from this github repo:

https://github.com/wizyoung/YOLOv3_TensorFlow

to implement the YOLO bounding box algorithm. In the training program, I get this error on these lines. I've gotten this error before and understand mostly what's going on. I've also used the "reuse = True" fix, but I don't understand what is going on here... the first couple lines of code are below:

```
from __future__ import division, print_function

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import logging
from tqdm import trange

import args

from utils.data_utils import get_batch_data
from utils.misc_utils import shuffle_and_overwrite, make_summary, config_learning_rate, config_optimizer, AverageMeter
from utils.eval_utils import evaluate_on_cpu, evaluate_on_gpu, get_preds_gpu, voc_eval, parse_gt_rec
from utils.nms_utils import gpu_nms

from model import yolov3

# setting loggers
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S', filename=args.progress_log_path, filemode='w')

# setting placeholders
is_training = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, name="phase_train")
handle_flag = tf.placeholder(tf.string, [], name='iterator_handle_flag')
# register the gpu nms operation here for the following evaluation scheme
pred_boxes_flag = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, None, None])
pred_scores_flag = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, None, None])
gpu_nms_op = gpu_nms(pred_boxes_flag, pred_scores_flag, args.class_num, args.nms_topk, args.score_threshold, args.nms_threshold)

##################
# tf.data pipeline
##################
train_dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(args.train_file)
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(args.train_img_cnt)
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(args.batch_size)
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(
    lambda x: tf.py_func(get_batch_data,
                         inp=[x, args.class_num, args.img_size, args.anchors, 'train', args.multi_scale_train, args.use_mix_up, args.letterbox_resize],
                         Tout=[tf.int64, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32]),
    num_parallel_calls=args.num_threads
)
train_dataset = train_dataset.prefetch(args.prefetech_buffer)

val_dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(args.val_file)
val_dataset = val_dataset.batch(1)
val_dataset = val_dataset.map(
    lambda x: tf.py_func(get_batch_data,
                         inp=[x, args.class_num, args.img_size, args.anchors, 'val', False, False, args.letterbox_resize],
                         Tout=[tf.int64, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32]),
    num_parallel_calls=args.num_threads
)
val_dataset.prefetch(args.prefetech_buffer)

iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(train_dataset.output_types, train_dataset.output_shapes)
train_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(train_dataset)
val_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(val_dataset)

# get an element from the chosen dataset iterator
image_ids, image, y_true_13, y_true_26, y_true_52 = iterator.get_next()
y_true = [y_true_13, y_true_26, y_true_52]

# tf.data pipeline will lose the data `static` shape, so we need to set it manually
image_ids.set_shape([None])
image.set_shape([None, None, None, 3])
for y in y_true:
    y.set_shape([None, None, None, None, None])

##################
# Model definition
##################
yolo_model = yolov3(args.class_num, args.anchors, args.use_label_smooth, args.use_focal_loss, args.batch_norm_decay, args.weight_decay, use_static_shape=False)
with tf.variable_scope('yolov3', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
    pred_feature_maps = yolo_model.forward(image, is_training=is_training)
loss = yolo_model.compute_loss(pred_feature_maps, y_true)
y_pred = yolo_model.predict(pred_feature_maps)

l2_loss = tf.losses.get_regularization_loss()

# setting restore parts and vars to update
saver_to_restore = tf.train.Saver(var_list=tf.contrib.framework.get_variables_to_restore(include=args.restore_include, exclude=args.restore_exclude))
update_vars = tf.contrib.framework.get_variables_to_restore(include=args.update_part)

tf.summary.scalar('train_batch_statistics/total_loss', loss[0])
tf.summary.scalar('train_batch_statistics/loss_xy', loss[1])
tf.summary.scalar('train_batch_statistics/loss_wh', loss[2])
tf.summary.scalar('train_batch_statistics/loss_conf', loss[3])
tf.summary.scalar('train_batch_statistics/loss_class', loss[4])
tf.summary.scalar('train_batch_statistics/loss_l2', l2_loss)
tf.summary.scalar('train_batch_statistics/loss_ratio', l2_loss / loss[0])

global_step = tf.Variable(float(args.global_step), trainable=False, collections=[tf.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES])
if args.use_warm_up:
    learning_rate = tf.cond(tf.less(global_step, args.train_batch_num * args.warm_up_epoch), 
                            lambda: args.learning_rate_init * global_step / (args.train_batch_num * args.warm_up_epoch),
                            lambda: config_learning_rate(args, global_step - args.train_batch_num * args.warm_up_epoch))
else:
    learning_rate = config_learning_rate(args, global_step)
tf.summary.scalar('learning_rate', learning_rate)

if not args.save_optimizer:
    saver_to_save = tf.train.Saver()
    saver_best = tf.train.Saver()

optimizer = config_optimizer(args.optimizer_name, learning_rate)

# set dependencies for BN ops

update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
    # train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss[0] + l2_loss, var_list=update_vars, global_step=global_step)
    # apply gradient clip to avoid gradient exploding
    gvs = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss[0] + l2_loss, var_list=update_vars)
    clip_grad_var = [gv if gv[0] is None else [
          tf.clip_by_norm(gv[0], 100.), gv[1]] for gv in gvs]
    train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(clip_grad_var, global_step=global_step)

if args.save_optimizer:
    print('Saving optimizer parameters to checkpoint! Remember to restore the global_step in the fine-tuning afterwards.')
    saver_to_save = tf.train.Saver()
    saver_best = tf.train.Saver()
```

and the full error message:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-948e13116df7> in <module>()
    114     clip_grad_var = [gv if gv[0] is None else [
    115           tf.clip_by_norm(gv[0], 100.), gv[1]] for gv in gvs]
--> 116     train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(clip_grad_var, global_step=global_step)
    117 
    118 if args.save_optimizer:

~\anaconda3\envs\newenvt\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\optimizer.py in apply_gradients(self, grads_and_vars, global_step, name)
    586                        ([str(v) for _, _, v in converted_grads_and_vars],))
    587     with ops.init_scope():
--> 588       self._create_slots(var_list)
    589     update_ops = []
    590     with ops.name_scope(name, self._name) as name:

~\anaconda3\envs\newenvt\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\momentum.py in _create_slots(self, var_list)
     75   def _create_slots(self, var_list):
     76     for v in var_list:
---> 77       self._zeros_slot(v, "momentum", self._name)
     78 
     79   def _prepare(self):

~\anaconda3\envs\newenvt\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\optimizer.py in _zeros_slot(self, var, slot_name, op_name)
   1132     named_slots = self._slot_dict(slot_name)
   1133     if _var_key(var) not in named_slots:
-> 1134       new_slot_variable = slot_creator.create_zeros_slot(var, op_name)
   1135       self._restore_slot_variable(
   1136           slot_name=slot_name, variable=var,

~\anaconda3\envs\newenvt\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\slot_creator.py in create_zeros_slot(primary, name, dtype, colocate_with_primary)
    179     return create_slot_with_initializer(
    180         primary, initializer, slot_shape, dtype, name,
--> 181         colocate_with_primary=colocate_with_primary)
    182   else:
    183     if isinstance(primary, variables.Variable):

~\anaconda3\envs\newenvt\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\slot_creator.py in create_slot_with_initializer(primary, initializer, shape, dtype, name, colocate_with_primary)
    153       with distribution_strategy.colocate_vars_with(primary):
    154         return _create_slot_var(primary, initializer, "", validate_shape, shape,
--> 155                                 dtype)
    156     else:
    157       return _create_slot_var(primary, initializer, "", validate_shape, shape,

~\anaconda3\envs\newenvt\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\slot_creator.py in _create_slot_var(primary, val, scope, validate_shape, shape, dtype)
     63       use_resource=resource_variable_ops.is_resource_variable(primary),
     64       shape=shape, dtype=dtype,
---> 65       validate_shape=validate_shape)
     66   variable_scope.get_variable_scope().set_partitioner(current_partitioner)
     67 

~\anaconda3\envs\newenvt\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py in get_variable(name, shape, dtype, initializer, regularizer, trainable, collections, caching_device, partitioner, validate_shape, use_resource, custom_getter, constraint, synchronization, aggregation)
   1465       constraint=constraint,
   1466       synchronization=synchronization,
-> 1467       aggregation=aggregation)
   1468 
   1469 

~\anaconda3\envs\newenvt\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py in get_variable(self, var_store, name, shape, dtype, initializer, regularizer, reuse, trainable, collections, caching_device, partitioner, validate_shape, use_resource, custom_getter, constraint, synchronization, aggregation)
   1215           constraint=constraint,
   1216           synchronization=synchronization,
-> 1217           aggregation=aggregation)
   1218 
   1219   def _get_partitioned_variable(self,

~\anaconda3\envs\newenvt\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py in get_variable(self, name, shape, dtype, initializer, regularizer, reuse, trainable, collections, caching_device, partitioner, validate_shape, use_resource, custom_getter, constraint, synchronization, aggregation)
    525           constraint=constraint,
    526           synchronization=synchronization,
--> 527           aggregation=aggregation)
    528 
    529   def _get_partitioned_variable(self,

~\anaconda3\envs\newenvt\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py in _true_getter(name, shape, dtype, initializer, regularizer, reuse, trainable, collections, caching_device, partitioner, validate_shape, use_resource, constraint, synchronization, aggregation)
    479           constraint=constraint,
    480           synchronization=synchronization,
--> 481           aggregation=aggregation)
    482 
    483     # Set trainable value based on synchronization value.

~\anaconda3\envs\newenvt\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py in _get_single_variable(self, name, shape, dtype, initializer, regularizer, partition_info, reuse, trainable, collections, caching_device, validate_shape, use_resource, constraint, synchronization, aggregation)
    846                          "reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope? "
    847                          "Originally defined at:\n\n%s" % (
--> 848                              name, "".join(traceback.format_list(tb))))
    849       found_var = self._vars[name]
    850       if not shape.is_compatible_with(found_var.get_shape()):

ValueError: Variable yolov3/yolov3_head/Conv/weights/Momentum/ already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True or reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope? Originally defined at:

  File "C:\Users\owenh\anaconda3\envs\newenvt\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1717, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()
  File "C:\Users\owenh\anaconda3\envs\newenvt\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3155, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\owenh\anaconda3\envs\newenvt\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 454, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
```

At first, I thought it was a compatibility issue with TF, but not so sure anymore.

Cheers,
Owen

Comment: Hi ! Please try the same after attaching  `"tf.reset_default_graph() "  at start of code.`  reference - https://www.programmersought.com/article/380863523/